# AND operation within mysql records

Tags: mysql, operators

I have a set of records which return flags in individual records. Based on that flags I want to perform `and` operation within those flags (e.g.if any single flag is "true" final result should return me "true")

Following are the set of records which is returned by normal SQL query ;

```
select ID,flag from tablename;
--------------------------
ID(int) | flag (varchar(5))
--------------------------
1       | true
2       | false
3       | true
4       | false
5       | false
```

I would like to know the SQL query which returns result as shown below (such a way that final result should be `and` operation within each of those 5 records)

```
 -------
   flag
 -------
   true
```

Comment: Take a look at the documentation: you are looking for "operators". There are millions of examples out there on google.

Comment: you want get only true flags ?

Comment: @arkascha I looked and tried "operators" I found solution using : Select BIT_OR(if(flag='true',true,false)) from tablename

Comment: OK, fine. One question: why do you store boolean values as _strings_ inside your database?

Comment: yes.I have also the same question .Perhaps this question can only be answred by the one who designed this DB long ago.. :)

Comment: My question to the one who down voted it.! why so..any explanation.!?

Comment: you said if all are true then result is true , or if one of the results is true then its true ??

Comment: @RowlandShaw: If there is a problem with a post, please describe the problem in detail, instead of just posting "what have you tried". See [this Meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172760/152134) on whether "what have you tried" comments are acceptable and alternatives to "what have you tried". Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you want to do, but if you want to define your `AND` operation as "at least one of the records must have as its flag value 'true'", you can use the following SQL statement which will return 1 if there is at least one 'true' value and otherwise will return 0:

SELECT IF(COUNT(*) > 0, 'true', 'false')
   FROM Table1
   WHERE flag = 'true';

See the SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e6cd7/11

Comment: exactly..!! correct.. Edit and in your if condition put 'true','false' for 1,0 respectively

Comment: @HardikBhalani if you are satisfied with the answer, could you accept it as the solution to your question?

Answer (score 0):

i came up with this solution but maybe you will get a short and better one :) .

```
 select if(count(*) = 1 , 'mixed' , flag) flag from(

 select flag from table1
 where flag = 'true' 
 having count(*) = 5
 union

 select flag from table1
 where flag = 'false' 
 having count(*) = 5
 union

 select 'mixed' from table1

 )t
```

[**DEMO TO PLAY WITH**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e6cd7/1)